# How to crop the image to remove the background

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image and I want to crop it. I have used Otsu's method and changed the image to its binary form. The binary image is:

[image: My original binary image]

I want to find the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax from this image so that I can crop the image such that only the leaf portion remains in the original image.

The image I need as output (in binary form):
[image: The image I want]

I don't want to use manual cropping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regionprops` to select your region of interest as follows:

```
BW = imread('wxK0w.jpg');
stats = regionprops(BW<128, 'BoundingBox', 'Area'); % The black region (lowest values) is the region you are interested in.
[~, iForeground] = max([stats.Area]); % assume the largest area is the foreground you want
box = round(stats(iForeground).BoundingBox);
BWcropped = BW(box(2) + (1:box(4)), box(1) + (1:box(3)));
imshow(BWcropped)
```

[image]